# Unique DT Instance with Angular DataTables

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I have Datatable in ng-repeat and want to be able to generate a unique dt-instance for all datatables in UI. This way I can have a unique instance of each table. Here is my template file with what is going on

```
      <li ng-repeat="batch in vm.batches">
                <div ng-show="batch.opened.submitted">
                      <table datatable="ng" class="table table-condensed dataTable" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-instance="**I WANT TO BE ABLE TO SET THIS TO SOMETHING UNIQUE**">
                                <thead>
                                       <tr>
                                              <th></th>                                                            
                                        </tr>
                                 </thead>
                                  <tbody>
                                         <tr ng-repeat="item in batch.PricingItems">
                                                <td>
                                                        <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="childInfo(item, batch.dtInstance, $event)" title="Click to view more">
                                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
                                                        </a>
                                                  </td>                                                           
                                         </tr>
                                   </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
           </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it unique by passing the `$index` value of the `ng-repeat`.

```
<li ng-repeat="batch in vm.batches track by $index">
   <div ng-show="batch.opened.submitted">
       <table datatable="ng" class="table table-condensed dataTable" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-instance="$index">
```

Comment: but there is no .DataTable since $index isn't an object, so if i wanted to access the DataTable in my controller, like dtInstance.DataTable, DataTable will be undefined